# Trying to break outer while loop from inner Try/except block

Tags: python

I want to break the while loop from try/except block and continue the for loop.

But break in try/except block is not working properly.

Is this the correct way of breaking while?

```
    for row in obj:
        url = URL_PATTERN.format(row['CONTEXT_ID'], row['TAGSET_ID'])
        driver.get(url)

        if set_status == "Closed":
            writer.writerow({'CONTEXT_ID': row['CONTEXT_ID'], 'TAGSET_ID': row['TAGSET_ID'], 'STATUS': 'Already Closed'})
        else:

            reopen_count = len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//input[@value='Reopen']"))

            r_count = 1
            build_xpath = "(//input[@value='Reopen'])[{}]".format
            while r_count <= reopen_count:
                driver.find_element_by_xpath(build_xpath(r_count)).click()
                driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@value='Completed']").click()
                try:
                    alert = driver.switch_to_alert()
                    alert.accept()
                    x_error = "Error"
                    r_count = r_count - 1
                    break
                except:
                    x_error = "NoError"

                r_count = r_count + 1


            if x_error == "Error":
                writer.writerow({'CONTEXT_ID': row['CONTEXT_ID'], 'TAGSET_ID': row['TAGSET_ID'], 'STATUS': 'Error'})
            else:
                writer.writerow({'CONTEXT_ID': row['CONTEXT_ID'], 'TAGSET_ID': row['TAGSET_ID'], 'STATUS': 'Closed'})
```

Comment: What does "not working properly" mean? What's the expected result? What result are you getting instead? Be specific.

Comment: As a side note, I think the way you have written seems wrong. you are reducing r_count in one place and incrementing r_count in another place.

Answer (score 0):

i think you should wrap the while block in try catch, just like that...

```
try:
    while r_count <= reopen_count:
        driver.find_element_by_xpath(build_xpath(r_count)).click()
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@value='Completed']").click()
        alert = driver.switch_to_alert()
        alert.accept()
        x_error = "Error"
        r_count = r_count - 1
        break
except:
    x_error = "NoError"
```